# Use Ionic super tabs inside ion-slides

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, swiper.js, ion-slides, supertab

I'm using angular 12 and ionic 5 and I'm trying to make a composed view with 2 pages swippeable. In the first view I have a super tabs section at bottom.

I put every page inside one ion-slide to make the pages swippeable but when I do that, the super tabs section becomes invisible. What's the problem?

```
<ion-content class="ion-padding">
  <ion-slides #mySlider>
    <ion-slide>

      (...Not relevant content...)

      <super-tabs>
        <super-tabs-toolbar scrollable slot="top" scrollablePadding="false">
          <super-tab-button>
            <ion-label>Tab1</ion-label>
          </super-tab-button>
          <super-tab-button>
            <ion-label>Tab2</ion-label>
          </super-tab-button>
        </super-tabs-toolbar>
        <super-tabs-container swipeEnabled="true">
          <super-tab>
            <ion-content>
              Tab #1
            </ion-content>
          </super-tab>
          <super-tab>
            <ion-content>
              Tab #2
            </ion-content>
          </super-tab>
        </super-tabs-container>
      </super-tabs>
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide>
      PAGE 2 (hidden until I swipe)
    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>
</ion-content>
```

What I marked as "not relevant content" keeps visible but super tabs disappear

Comment: Why not put the tabs in ion-footer?

Comment: Why in a footer?

Comment: you want the tabs visible on all pages (slides), right? then it should be in the ion-footer

Comment: No, I want the tabs in the first slide